How to find out metric for different line bundles over complex projective space
(Tautological line bundle on $\mathbb{C P}^n$) The point on $\gamma_n$ is $(\ell, z) \in \mathbb{C P}^n \times \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$. It is natural to define a Hermitian metric $h$ on $\gamma_n$ by $h(\ell, z)=|z|^2$. Now we study it in local coordinates. If $h_i$ is the metric of $h$ on $U_i$, then we have
$$
h(\ell, z)=h_i(\ell) z_i \bar{z}_i=h_i(\ell)\left|z_i\right|^2.\tag1
$$
So in the coordinates $\left(U_i, \theta\right)$, for $\ell=\left[z_0, \cdots, z_n\right]$,
$$
h_i(\ell)=\frac{|z|^2}{\left|z_i\right|^2}=1+|\theta|^2 .
$$
The author said it is natural to define the metric $h(\ell,z)=|z|^2$, but I couldn't get it. Like does it mean we are defining the metric over the attached fiber space $\mathbb C^{n+1}$? (metric on $\mathbb C^{n+1}$) If I am not wrong then the trivialization over $U_i\subset\mathbb{CP}^n$ is,
\begin{align*}
\phi_i:\pi^{-1}(U_i)&\rightarrow U_i\times\mathbb C\\
(\ell,z)&\mapsto(\ell,z_i)
\end{align*}
I didn't understand how $h(\ell,z)$ become $h_i(\ell)z_i\bar z_i$ over $U_i$ in $(1)$.

Question 1: How the author come up with the expression used in $(1)$?

What if I take other line bundle defined over $\mathbb{CP}^n$? Like dual of the tautological line bundle and canonical line bundle?
I try to compute the metric for torus, $S^1 \times S^1 \overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} S^1$. Here I don't want to use the parametrization for torus (because it uses the inner product from ambient space),
\begin{align*}
x(\theta ,\varphi )&=(R+r\cos \theta )\cos {\varphi }\\
y(\theta ,\varphi )&=(R+r\cos \theta )\sin {\varphi }\\
z(\theta ,\varphi )&=r\sin \theta
\end{align*}
It's felt like I didn't know how to find out metric without parametrization.

Question 2: How to compute Riemannian metric without parametrization like for torus case?

Is there any good reference where I can have some illustrative examples to compute metric without parametrization?

I'm not sure if you're asking (i) What motivates the stated metric on the tautological bundle; (ii) How to define metrics on other line bundles over projective space; (iii) Something about the torus; (iv) How to think up metrics generally; or (v) Something else. <> Can you please edit the question to clarify, and to focus on one question? :)

Sorry for the confusion. I felt I didn't know how to compute metric without parametrization. Like for more general space/bundle, what's the procedure to compute that. I encounter the issue while reading the first paragraph. And realize that. @AndrewD.Hwang I also try to rephrase my questions. Thanks for your suggestion.

There are lots of metrics on the torus. To use the metric induced from the standard embedding in $\Bbb R^3$, yes, you need the parametrization. But you can also use the flat metric $d\theta\otimes d\theta+ d\phi\otimes d\phi$.

Thank you very much @TedShifrin Can you suggest any reference where I can find such example. And can you say something on Question 1? Thanks again.

$\newcommand{\Numbers}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\newcommand{\Cpx}{\Numbers{C}}\newcommand{\Reals}{\Numbers{R}}\newcommand{\Ints}{\Numbers{Z}}\newcommand{\Ocal}{\mathcal{O}}$The quick answer to Question 1 is "Yes, we're inducing a metric on the tautological bundle by restricting (or pulling back by inclusion) the standard flat Hermitian metric on $\Cpx^{n+1}$."
(To address the struck-out question about other line holomorphic bundles over complex projective space: If $h$ locally represents a metric on the tautological bundle $\Ocal(-1)$, then for each integer $k$, the $k$th power $h^{k}$ represents a metric on $\Ocal(-k)$.)

The wording suggests there may be a couple of conceptual snags.

There is a difference between a Riemannian metric on a smooth manifold (such as a torus) and an Hermitian metric on a complex vector bundle (such as a holomorphic line bundle over complex projective space).
There is a difference between calculating a metric and exhibiting a metric.

I mention the first item only because both types of metric are asked about. For definiteness, below I'll write about Riemannian metrics, mostly on the torus $M = S^{1} \times S^{1}$.
As I read it, the second item is the main issue. In order to calculate a metric on $M$ (as I would use the term), we need constraints that uniquely determine a metric on $M$ up to isometry. These constraints might be

Geometric, e.g., $M$ is the set of points at distance $\pi/4$ from a great circle in the round unit $3$-sphere;
Analytic, e.g., our metric is flat, and there exist equal-length shortest geodesics intersecting at right angles;
Algebraic, e.g., $M$ is the image of the mapping
$$
X(u, v) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2} - \sin v}(\cos u, \sin u, \cos v),
$$
or is the zero locus of $\bigl(\sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}} - R\bigr)^{2} + z^{2} = r^{2}$ for some real numbers $0 < r < R$.

(These are not sharply-defined categories, but qualitative, fuzzy, and overlapping.)
By contrast, to exhibit a metric on $M$ (as I would use the term), it suffices to write down metric components with respect to any convenient coordinates. For the torus, we can easily write down every Riemannian metric in terms of arbitrary real-valued functions of two variables: If $E$, $F$, and $G$ are real-valued functions of $(u, v)$ (as smooth as we like), are $2\pi$-periodic in each variable, and if $EG - F^{2}$ is everywhere positive, then
$$
g = E(u, v)\, du^{2} + F(u, v)(du\, dv + dv\, du) + G(u, v)\, dv^{2}
$$
may be viewed as a Riemannian metric on the torus $(\Reals/2\pi\Ints)^{2}$. Conversely, every Riemannian metric on the torus induces such an expression when we lift to the universal cover.
Playing the same game on other manifolds (such as the $2$-sphere) isn't as nice in practice, because there are not generally such nice effectively-global coordinates. Still, if we have a sufficiently-concrete intrinsic description of a manifold, namely if we have a covering by coordinate charts, and we know the overlap maps, we can exhibit a Riemannian metric in each chart, subject only to the compatibility that the metrics we define in two charts agree where both are defined.
For the two-sphere, reasonable choices include geographic coordinates (though these are a little vexing to be Scrupulously Careful about at the poles) and stereographic coordinates from the north and south poles. For the real projective plane, we can instead write metrics on the sphere that are invariant under the antipodal map.
On the subject of writing metrics in local coordinates, every surface metric, whether on the torus or not, can be written in the form above on a dense subset of $M$. What that tells us is, there are non-trivial, and usually non-obvious relationships between global properties of the components $E$, $F$, and $G$ (for the torus this was hidden in the word "periodic"!) and "how to complete the metric" or "how to fill in the missing points" or "what surface $M$ the metric lives on."
<>
If our goal is merely to exhibit metrics, we obtain an infinite-dimensional space's worth just by writing down a single metric $g_{0}$: For each smooth, real-valued function $\phi$ on our manifold, $g_{\phi} = e^{2\phi}g_{0}$ is another metric. The point of view I secretly hope you're reaching yourself is, exhibiting metrics is pretty easy, and also (once you "see behind the curtain") not very interesting without additional geometric guidance.
For myself, "guidance" generally means something like this: Suppose a Riemannian metric on the sphere or torus comes from a parametrization, i.e., from an embedding in Euclidean three-space. Scale this metric as in the preceding paragraph. Can we find another embedding for which the pullback metric is isometric to the scaled metric? If the answer is "yes" I feel as if I understand the scaled metric.
The point here is, there are at least two different ways of "perturbing" an embedded Riemannian metric: (i) Perturb the embedding, and (ii) perturb the metric (e.g., by scaling, or by changing the metric components more generally). Getting from (i) to (ii) is routine computation. Getting from (ii) to (i) is Deep Water, globally solving nonlinear PDEs or proving solutions do not exist.
With more experience, one develops intuition about intrinsic geometry (loosely, "what it's like to live inside a Riemannian manifold"), and then it becomes possible to "see" certain types of perturbation. For example, if we puncture a compact Riemannian manifold by removing one point $p$, and multiply the metric by a function that blows up sufficiently rapidly at $p$, we get a complete metric, loosely because we've dragged the puncture to infinite distance.
Incidentally, it's worth thinking about why we need "sufficiently rapid blow-up"!

 Secretly, this is an exercise in second-semester calculus, specifically the divergence of improper integrals on bounded intervals.

<>
These remarks partly explain why students starting out are generally shown metrics defined using a parametrization:

Metrics induced by a parametrization are relatively easy to calculate and understand geometrically.
Inversely, it's easy to exhibit metrics that do not come directly from a parametrization, but hard to "see" the result geometrically.
Further, when we have only a local expression of a metric, it's generally hard even to see topologically "how to extend to a complete manifold" in which our metric is dense.


Thank you very much for your detail answer (+1) @AndrewD.Hwang. I will read the answer and update you if I face any problem. I really never see such description into any books. It will be a great help if you suggest some resources where I can find more information. Thanks again.

Resources are tricky to suggest: Arguably, the ideas here are just the definition of a Riemannian metric together with geometric intuition from the first three semesters of calculus! That said, I remember developing these perspectives from reading papers that treat the space of Riemannian metrics (such as Kazdan-Warner's 1974 Annals paper on Gaussian curvature), doing research (e.g., constructing metrics in projectivized vector bundles, talking to physicists), and teaching multivariable calculus and differential geometry (which makes one see familiar tools as if they're new).
